# In XML how I Get the value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I want to get the all nodes value with the same name in VB.NET. Here are sample xml:

```
<ReferenceNumber>
    <Value>54802449</Value>
</ReferenceNumber>-
<ReferenceNumber>
    <Value>288286.2</Value>
</ReferenceNumber>-
<ReferenceNumber>
    <Value>SWTB1277</Value>
</ReferenceNumber>
```

I use this code

```
   Dim oPackageReferenceNumberValueNode As XmlNode
 oNode = oDoc.DocumentElement
                            oNodeList = oNode.SelectNodes("/QuantumViewResponse/QuantumViewEvents/SubscriptionEvents/SubscriptionFile/Manifest")
 oPackageReferenceNumberValueNode = oNodeList(1).SelectNodes("ReferenceNumber/Value")(1)
  oPackageReferenceNumberValueNodeForProduct = oNodeList(1).SelectNodes("ReferenceNumber/Value")(2)
```

but It take from index 0 and 1 but not from 2 why?

Answer (score 0):

For parsing XML with VB.Net, you need to use the System.XML namespace.

To query attributes:

```
xNode.Attributes(attributeName).Value.ToString
```

Check the following tutorial

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/XML-Programming-VB.NET.aspx

Comment: but I have same name tag then how can I get

Comment: you can iterate over oNodeList using For Each instead and get the ReferenceNumber/Value node